# How to get uploaded file path in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

asp code:

```
      If FileUpload1.PostedFile IsNot Nothing Then
        Try
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("~/F:\ImageUploaded\")
           Span1.InnerHtml = "Upload Successful!"
         Dim path as string
         path=????
        Catch ex As Exception
           Span1.InnerHtml = "Error saving file <b>C:\" + File1.Value & "</b><br>" & ex.ToString()
        End Try
    End If
```

What code should i write to get the path of uploaded file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);

System.IO.DirectoryInfo DI = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: I require at least 15 reputation to mark an answer useful.@Vignesh Kumar